# Java RegEX To Split and Reverse String

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java String `"test/this/string"` that I want to reverse to `"string/this/test"` using a regular expression or the most efficient Java algorithm.  The way I know is to use the split method, loop over the array and rebuild the string manually.  The number of "/" can vary and doesn't occur a fixed number of times.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with the method you described?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, using [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int,%20int%29):

```
String str = "string/this/test";

StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(str.length());

int start = str.lastIndexOf('/'), end = str.length();

while (start >= 0) {
    rev.append(str.substring(start + 1, end));
    rev.append('/');

    end = start;
    start = str.lastIndexOf('/', start - 1);
}

rev.append(str.substring(0, end));

System.out.println(rev);
```

```
test/this/string
```

Comment: Skip the conversion to List and call to reverse. You can directly iterate over the split array in reverse order!

Comment: @isnot2bad You're absolutely right, I was being unnecessarily fancy.

Comment: I'm still puzzled how complex this is in Java. Should be a one-liner. This is the reason why Perl and PHP guys are sometimes laughing about us... ;) Btw.: Your Collections.reverse version comes back into play with Java 8 'cause then String.join can be used for joining a split-array. Still three lines of code then...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line using regex:

```
String reversed = str.replaceAll("(.*?)(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?(/.*?)?", "$9$8$7$6$5$4$3$2$1").replaceAll("^/", "");;
```

The way this works is the regex matches the whole string and captures the parts as separate groups, then the replacement string has back referenced to those captured groups to put them back in the reverse order.

This works for 1-9 parts.

Comment: Presumably the number of `/`s will not be known before hand.

Comment: @arshajii didn't read it like that. You could be right. If not, thus works. If so, not. Although, I've made it work for 1-9 parts now.

Comment: @c12 this works for any number from one to nine. That's the limit of group reference numbers. If a max of nine is acceptable, then this solution is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
String input = "test/this/string";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split("(?=/)|(?<=/)"));
Collections.reverse(list);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: list)
   sb.append(s);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

`(?<=/)` is a zero-length matching regex that matches if the previous character is a `/`.
`(?=/)` is a zero-length matching regex that matches if the next character is a `/`.

So `(?=/)|(?<=/)` matches right before and after each `/`, thus the `split` splits the string into `"test", "/", "this", "/", "string"`.

[Test](http://ideone.com/MIWbn4).

Comment: You are missing the "/" in your result!